# RepeatWith property in RDLC Report

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc

What is the use of `RepeatWith` propery in a RDLC report?

I am trying to create a report which has a list, in the list there is 1 table and 1 textbox which is aligned to the right of the page and has 1cm width and full page height, like a marker.

My problem is that if the table takes more than one page, my marker textbox is only displayed for the first page. I thought the `RepeatWith` property would help me, but I don't get what it does.

See my paint work :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use RepeatWith in data region which contains data region, in your example you have textbox inside a list (data region), which again contain a table (data region).

I've tried to put one table which will render around 5 pages, so it will be repeated, and one textbox in line with table, where I set RepeatWith referencing on tablix.

When I preview report, I see 4-5 pages, and on all of them I see my textbox.

Comment: So, its not what I need, because in the green field, I need to see the title that is grouped by the parent list. However, I have tried the same thing as you did, but the textbox only showed up once. My work-around was to fix the number of records in Table to 43 and put another variable `page` to group on it.

Comment: Which SSRS version you use?

Comment: It is version 11 with VS2012